# Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException in

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I am trying to get Users facebook profile picture and its thumbnail and adding it to the parse class after downloading it . Take a look

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String[] Params) 
{

    String accessToken = AccessToken ;
    String email = EMAIL;
    profile =  com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    User.put("displayName", profile.getName());
    User.put("facebookId", profile.getId());
    User.setUsername(profile.getId());
    try
    {
            User.put("FBaccessToken", accessToken);
            User.setEmail(email);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

        Log.e("ERROR","Failed");
    }
    User.setPassword(profile.getId() + profile.getId());
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    query.whereEqualTo("username", profile.getId());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {
                //brace the lord no error
                if (list == null)
                {
                    parseSignUp() ;
                }
                else
                {
                    if  (list.isEmpty())
                    {
                        parseSignUp() ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        login(profile.getId(), (profile.getId() + profile.getId()));
                    }
                    for (ParseObject str : list)
                    {
                            Log.e("ERROR", "what ?");
                    }
                }


            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("ERROR", "not");

            }
        }
    });
    return "done";
   }
```

Login.java

```
   SendFeedBackJob newJob = new SendFeedBackJob();

                                    newJob.progressBar = progressBar ;


                                    newJob.EMAIL = email ;
                                    newJob.AccessToken = accessToken.getToken();

                                    newJob.invisible = View.INVISIBLE ;

                                    newJob.show = View.VISIBLE ;
                                    newJob.execute();
```

Even if network stuff is in AsyncTask still this code throws me this error

```
  12-04 19:02:27.773    4263-4263/com.socketmill.thisismohit.vine       E/ERROR﹕android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
  12-04 19:02:27.803    4263-4263/com.socketmill.thisismohit.vine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.parse.ParseFile.<init>(ParseFile.java:188)
        at com.parse.ParseFile.<init>(ParseFile.java:218)
        at com.socketmill.thisismohit.vine.SendFeedBackJob.parseSignUp(SendFeedBackJob.java:207)
        at com.socketmill.thisismohit.vine.SendFeedBackJob$1.done(SendFeedBackJob.java:90)
        at com.socketmill.thisismohit.vine.SendFeedBackJob$1.done(SendFeedBackJob.java:75)
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you're getting a NullPointerException, that's the one that crashes your app.

Comment: Please narrow the sample code to the minimum that reproduces the problem. Something seems to be missing which causes the NPE.

Comment: What line is SendFeedBackJob.java:207?

Comment: E/ERROR﹕android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException this error is exactly what you may suspect. You are probably using network on your main UI thread.

Comment: @somerandomusername I am using the network service inside the  geByteArrayFromURL() which I am calling inside doInBackground() , I just fail to understand how this is surfacing

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla 
 
the null Pointer exception is not the problem , android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException is and that occurs in the function geByteArrayFromURL() when i try to download from the network

Comment: "//brace the lord no error" , perhaps lord is angry that you are bracing him. Perhaps try praising the lord, and all your errors will go away. But you are right, it is inside AsyncTask hmm...

Comment: @somerandomusername this still wont work :(

Comment: your are not calling `getByteArrayFromURL` in `doInBackground`,  you are calling it in `done`, which is on the UI thread.

Comment: @njzk2 but if ParseQuery is called from doInBackground, shouldn't it stay on that Thread ? Guess not

Comment: No, the callback will use whatever Thread called it. If you run for example: `(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())).post(new Runnable() { public void run() { // UI THREAD }});` inside `doInBackground` will run the code within `run()` on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindInBackground's done callback method runs on UI thread and not on the async thread

Answer (score 2):

Just because it starts off in doInBackground, does not mean that the entire code inside that is running in the background thread. Perhaps a library you are using is sending providing a callback using the UI Thread.

Reading the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/FindCallback.html), the `query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {})` method will run the `public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e)` method on the **UI Thread**.

That means that your `parseSignUp()` method, and thus, your `geByteArrayFromURL` method are also running on the UI Thread.

Infact, considering the fact that the Parse Library handles this all for you. You should probably remove the Parse Library from the AsyncTask entirely. Since it is going to go to `onPostExecute()` before the library finishes executing (you start a new thread inside `doInBackground`.

Comment: Interesting , let me try this

Comment: This works like magic , just added some booleans working if the user is found and right after the callback i checked for the flag and called parseSignup() and hell it works . Thanks man